# Why Did Time Machine Delete My Old Backups?

Tags: time-machine

I recently upgraded my hard drive from the stock Hitachi 250GB to a Western Digital 320GB. I restored from Time Machine.

I plugged in my hard drive today and left my hard drive to back up. Surprisingly, when I came back, the backups were being deleted.

Why?

It was the same installation. Now my unrecoverable backups are gone.

Comment: Were you (close to) out of space on the external drive?

Comment: The signature likely changed with the new drive, but my experience is that it wouldn't back up rather than deleting them. Perhaps it is different if using Time Machine without a Time Capsule? Not having to deal with multiple machines, maybe it just overwrites what is there if the signature is different? Just a guess.

Comment: Nathan - 90GB left on the HD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a full restore, a full backup is preformed (always). It's by design. This is also documented on the wonderful [Podini - About Time Machine](http://web.me.com/pondini/Time_Machine/Home.html) site, section [TM is doing a full backup for no good reason](http://web.me.com/pondini/Time_Machine/D3.html). Other circumstances, that may trigger full backup, are listed too.

I quote:

> **And Time Machine may do a full backup after any of the following:**
>    * A full restore, whether from Time Machine or a "clone" (probably)